# PHP json_encode($_POST) and mySQL issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to `json_encode($_POST)` in PHP, but I have one small problem.

On my `$_POST` sometimes I get some encoded JSON as example below:

```
Array
(
    [module] => {"media":true}
)
```

Where `module` contains a JSON string. My problem is when I use `json_encode($POST);` I get a result like this:

```
{"module":"{\"petMedia\":true}"}
```

Trying to insert into mySQL JSON column, I get this error

```
Invalid JSON text: "Missing a comma or '}' after an object member.
```

It's not possible for me to decode the string before because not always I get encoded JSON.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a loop with conditional checks! (but wouldn't it be easier just to clean up what is POSTing to the script in the first place so its not sending mixed content?)

Comment: you should use `json_decode` not `json_encode` if you have string as `{"media":true}`, [Check it](https://eval.in/915833)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had POST variables coming in where sometimes they have json encoded in it, or not... one way to handle it, would be a cleanup loop.

Lets say this is the POST in:

```
$_POST -> 'var1' = 'some string'
       -> 'var2' = '2315'
       -> 'var3' = '{"some":"json"}'
```

Now, I would setup a little cleaner, because you cannot just `json_encode($_POST)` as you found out. It double encodes the `var3`.

```
$clean = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    json_decode($val);// test
    if (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        $clean[$key] = json_decode($val);// $val is json, so pre-decode it
    } else {
        $clean[$key] = $val;// its not real json, so assign straight
    }
}
print_r($clean);
print_r(json_encode($clean));
```

Results in:

```
Array (
    [var1] => some string
    [var2] => 2315
    [var3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [some] => json
        )
)
// this then is a json encoded string, which is good:
{"var1":"some string","var2":2315,"var3":{"some":"json"}}
```

Basically, this then makes a full object which you can now store into the database safely, since all variables and their values are json encodable.

I hope this helps you get started, and you dont actually have normal variables inside json strings, that are not json encoded, and and and and ;)

Comment: Dude, that's definitely worth 2 cents. Should have thought of that.. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on a theme perhaps

```
/* emulate POST */
$_POST=array(
    'php'=>'fantastic',
    'javascript'=>'awesome',
    'asp'=>'awful',
    'module'=>json_encode( array( 'media' => true ) )
);

/* process the POST array and decode any json data within */
array_walk( $_POST, function( &$value ){
    $tmp=json_decode( $value );
    if( json_last_error() == 0 )$value=$tmp;
});

/* encode the POST data */
$encoded=json_encode( $_POST );
```

Outputs:

```
{"php":"fantastic","javascript":"awesome","asp":"awful","module":{"media":true}}
```